# Generating and Downloading CSV file using apache common csv

Tags: java, spring, export-to-csv, apache-commons

I have used the below method to generate and download a csv file from database

```
String path= request.getServletContext().getRealPath("assets/file.csv");
        try{
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(path));
            CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(bufferedWriter, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("Name"));
            for(String name: names){
                csvPrinter.printRecord(name);
            }
            csvPrinter.flush();
            csvPrinter.close();
            jsonObject.addProperty("result", "succ");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And i'm using ajax to call this method. 
My jsp file where calling this method

```
<% String file= request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()
    + request.getContextPath() + "/assets/file.csv";
%>
<button id="download" type="button">Download</button>
<a id="file" target="_blank" href="<%= file%>" style="display: none"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#download').on('click', function(){
                $.ajax({
                    //ajax code
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        var resp = JSON.parse(response);
                        if(resp.result == "succ"){
                            document.getElementById("file").click();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, err){

                    }
                });
            });
```

But the issue is when I'm trying to download the file for first time it is returning 404 page and when i'm running again it is returning the last generated file.

After debugging I found that the file is getting generated late.

Comment: Post the code where you are trying to download the csv file.

Comment: @Sambit updated the jsp file